# Ошибка: No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: mysql, servlet, tomcat

В сервлете пытаюсь подключиться к БД и выполнить запрос. Возникает ошибка. Сервлет инициализируется, подключение осуществляется, однако ошибка: No operations allowed after connection closed, говорит о том что нельзя выполнять операции когда соединение закрыто, но явно соединение не закрывал. При удалении закрытий соединений с сервлета и класса подключения к БД ошибка такая же.

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import my.service.db.MySqlConnector;

public class DataFromDb extends HttpServlet {
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("DataFromDb service()");
        Connection conn=null;
        try {
             conn = MySqlConnector.getConnection();
            System.out.println(conn);
            Statement stat  = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dataonrussian");;

            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("familia"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                                    }

            }
}
```

Код ошибки сервера TomCat следующий:

```
DataFromDb service()
Connect
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@3650710f
SQL Exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1296)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:2655)
    at servlets.DataFromDb.service(DataFromDb.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Код для соединения с БД:

```
package my.service.db;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class MySqlConnector {
        public static Connection getConnection(){
                Connection conn = null;
                String path ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db";
                String user = "root";
                String password = "12";
                try {
        Class.forName(path);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connect");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    try {
            conn.close();
                   }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return conn;
    }
    }
```

Comment: а код класса MySqlConnector где?

Comment: добавил к основному коду.

Comment: так а для чего у вас в MySqlConnector.getConnection() блок finally, который закрывает только что открытое соединение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы же сам закрываете `connection` в методе `MySqlConnector.getConnection()`, перед тем как его вернуть. Вы этого не видите? Выкинем все "лишнее":

```
public Connection getConnection()
{
    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    return conn;
}
```